# How to convert to android sdk 3 from sdk 2 to make post to feed

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I use to post to the feed this way

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
        String descriptionString = description.ToString();
        params.putString("name", this.getString(R.string.app_name));
        params.putString("caption", "Caption");
        params.putString("description", descriptionString);
        params.putString("link", "http://www.cnn.com");
        params.putString("message", "this is the message");
        params.putString("picture","http://www.mydomains.com/logo_1.png");

        this._facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new PostDialogListener());
```

but now

```
 this._facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new PostDialogListener());
```

has a line through dialog saying it is deprecated. There is no suggestion on how to do it now? How do I convert this piece of code to use the new sdk. I looked at the documenatation here but no mention of dialog

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/#requests

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [WebDialog class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog). And in your case, you'll want to look at the [WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder).

Answer (score -1):

In AndroidManifest file just type this piece of code...

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" android:maxSdkVersion="3"/>
```

Comment: I think version 2 and 3 are the FB api versions and not android APIs

Comment: those are android api versions once add this code to ur manifest and check

Comment: Yes. The original post meant with android sdk 3 and android sdk 2 the FB android sdk 2/3 and not Android API version 2/3.